# Why is Priya not talking backwards in this scene?

Tags: tenet

Protagonist, Neil, and wounded Kat entered into turnstile. Now they entered
inverted world. They steal ambulance from airport. Now Protagonist met invereted
Priya here. Here Priya is inverted because it's inverted world. Then why Priya
not talking backwards?

[image]

Comment: From your question: "Priya is inverted and so is the protagonist". So they're both talking backwards (w.r.t. us).

Comment: Why do you think they're both inverted in this scene?  As I recall, most of the time the protagonist was inverted was spent traveling to the freeport, and once he was there, he went through the turnstile and became uninverted again.

Answer (score 4):

> Protagonist, Neil, and wounded Kat entered into turnstile.

... in Oslo

> Now they entered inverted world.

The world is never inverted. That's the whole point of the movie, preventing the world from getting inverted. They travel, inverted, to Oslo; and the turnstyle inverts them again, i.e. un-inverts them.

> They steal ambulance from airport.

> Now Protagonist met invereted Priya here.

Nope. Non-inverted protagonist meets non-inverted Priya.

> Here Priya is inverted because it's inverted world.

She isn't, because it isn't. Problem solved :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Here Priya is inverted because it's inverted world. Then why Priya not talking backwards?

Neither of them are inverted; they would have to be wearing the oxygen masks otherwise. The oxygen masks (besides the full on gas masks where it is hard to tell) are a good way to tell who is inverted and who is not.

As a side note, when there are multiple people moving in different directions, Cristopher Nolan does a good job establishing the red and blue color scheme.